# Word Embedding using Negative Sampling

Tags: python, word2vec

I want to write the code for word2vec with Negative Sampling. I am putting the pseudo code for that below

1. Add one hot vector for 'context' and 'target' word, as each row.
   This means each example has 2 ones and rest all 0s.
2. In the 'context' and 'target'  sample is found in corpus, y is 1.
       Else y is 0. for every positive 'context' and 'target'  sample,
       there were K(=4) Negative samples.
3. At this point i created a single Neural Network, with RELU and
       Sigmoid activation functions, to get the word Embeddings.

After this i felt that the word Embeddings were incorrect.

Is there anything  wrong in my approach ?

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks

Sachin Gupta

Comment: Can you please attach the code? :)

Comment: There are many existing word2vec libraries in Python – so even if you want to do your own, a good way to test your code for correctness is to run the same training-data and evaluation against both your code, and one or more of the other proven, widely-used implementations. If the end results are of similar quality, that's good evidence your implementation is OK! (And if it's not, comparing your steps/choices with the working libraries may narrow-in on any errors better than a generic, code-free request for guidance.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
You can have a look at the code here https://www.kaggle.com/sachingg/fork-of-imdb-review-using-word2vec/

I have taken the corpus from another code, which you can see here: 
https://github.com/sudharsan13296/Word2vec-from-scratch/blob/master/word2vec%20scratch.ipynb

The results i find are totally different.

Thanks
Sachin

Comment: Any reason for tagging this question `mit-scratch`?

Comment: Seems like a mistake. Tag removed. Thanks